# How to make Find in File dialog appear floating in front not attached in the corner in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, dialog, user-friendly

I have a very large screen and poor vision. Working with Visual Studion 2022 it is very difficult for me to move my head and the whole body to that far top corner of the screen to reach find in file little box. While Ctrl+Shipt+F only shows "Find-in-Files". How to make the small docked "Find-in-this-file" dialog appear as a normal dialog and in the center, and preferrably near where the cursor is?

I tried Visual Studio 2022 and internet search, but it seems to me it is a very obscure problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the down pointing arrow and choose float.
That should make in more usable in your case.

Alternative, right click top bar of the search and choose float.

[image: find in files floating]

Comment: This is "Find-in-Files" dialog. You can search the current document here, but you have to make a choice in "Look in" combobox which is annoying and time consuming.

Comment: But isn't the look in option remembering the last chosen option? Can't try it out for the moment.

Comment: Mr-awk, there is another "find in current file" dialog which pops up when ctrl-F. This one is stuck to the top-right corner. If you have a very large screen, it is very uncofortable to operate with it.  It is unmoveable.
I would give you a picture, but I am not allowed yet.

Comment: I see what you mean, the counter action that lead to the new quick find (Ctrl + f) is that the old one could hide search results and lead to moving the box around. The action you do is to use the (Ctrl + shift + f) box and set "look in" to "current document" and then use that. Sorry to say, today's solution with the small quick find window is requested from 2010-ish, so it's likely to stay that way.